# How to process the file being downloaded chunk by chunk using GridFSBucket

Tags: python, pymongo, gridfs

My objective is  to write python script, which reads text file using gridfs.
And iterate line by line thru it.
When i use, `gridfs.get()`, noticed I was getting chunk of bytes in each iteration.Can you please guide me , how to iterate line by line with "get".

I'm able to manage this, by using `GridFsBucket` and storing the data un-necessarily in temporary file, and opening again in read mode to iterate line by line. Looking for a better way to handle this.

```
    file_store = GridFSBucket(db)
    file = open('test.txt', 'wb')
    file_store.download_to_stream(raw_file[0].get('ObjectId'),file)
    if not file:
        return None
    file.close()
    file=open('test.txt','rb')
    for line in file:
        .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to achieve this using `GridFSBucket`, and `open_download_stream`.

Below is the sample code:

```
file_store = GridFSBucket(mongo.db, bucket_name=<fs CollectionName>)

file_handler = file_store.open_download_stream(object_id)

eachline=file_handler.readline()
while eachline:
   .........processss
   eachline = file_handler.readline()
```